# Building triangle with nested loops

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to build a triangle using nested loops.

```js
var line, triangle;
line = triangle = "";

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    line += "#";
  }
  triangle += line + "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

I expected that each row is more than the last by only one "#" like this:
[image]

But this is the result I got:
[image]

Comment: You probably want to start with an empty line.

Comment: You shouldn't need two loops for this. Keep two variables, one for the result and another for the current row. Append the current row to the result each loop

Comment: @will.fiset I'll try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does it is you are updating `line` on each iteration and you keep appending to it. If you want to do the nested loops, than you need to reset the variable line each time you are in the outer loop.

```js
var line, triangle;
line = triangle = "";

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  line =""
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    line += "#";
  }
  triangle += line + "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

Or you can keep what you have and dump the inner loop and every iteration you just add one character to the line.

```js
var line, triangle;
line = triangle = "";

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  line += "#";
  triangle += line + "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

Comment: This is much cleaner. Thanks

Comment: That second snippet is especially clean. I like it for being optimized in time-complexity

Answer (score 2):

You need to empty your line before each nested iteration. Without this you have one line and every time concatenate new items to it. Also you can leave the `line` variable and just use the `triangle`.

```js
var triangle = '';

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    triangle += "#";
  }
  triangle += "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

You can also try this solution with [String#repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
var triangle = '';

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  triangle += '#'.repeat(row) + '\n';
}

console.log(triangle);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function triangle(num) {
for(let i = '#'; i.length < num; i+='#') {
    console.log(i)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
function generatePyramid() {
    var totalNumberofRows = 7;
    var output="";
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output+= "#  ";
        }
        print(output);
        output="";
    }
}  
generatePyramid();
```

How it works: http://rextester.com/ULY85622

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Fixed it by just adding one line - you need to reinitialize the variable "line" after each row iteration

```js
var line, triangle;
line = triangle = "";

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  line="";
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    line += "#";
  }
  triangle += line + "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `line` after each loop because it is accumulating all `#` on each cycle:

```js
var line, triangle;
line = triangle = "";

for (var row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
  line = "" // Add this line
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    line += "#";
  }
  triangle += line + "\n";
}

console.log(triangle);
```

Your code is incorrect because line follows the following steps on each cycle:

- row 1: `line` starts as '' and ends as `#` (Adds `#`)
- row 2: `line` starts as `#` and ends as `###` (Adds `##`)
- row 3: `line` starts as `###` and ends as `######` (Adds `###`)
- row 4: `line` starts as `######` and ends as `##########` (Adds `####`)
- row 5: `line` starts as `##########` and ends as `###############` (Adds `#####`)
- row 6: `line` starts as `###############` and ends as `#####################` (Adds `######`)
- row 7: `line` starts as `#####################` and ends as `############################` (Adds `#######`)